# Since water boils at room temperature in a near vacuum, is it possible to use this to generate electricity in some way?

Tags: electricity, water, vacuum

This may be a blatantly obvious question but I've never heard about such a thing happening. Could this be possible in some way using a vacuum chamber to boil the water and spin a turbine?

Comment: How would you generate the vacuum in the chamber? And how much energy might that take?

Comment: To expand on @tpg2114's comment - as soon as the water starts boiling, you don't have a vacuum any more unless you keep pumping out the steam, and that will use more power than you will get from your proposed steam turbine.

Comment: You might also consider a related question: whether you could transport water to some hot region where the outside temperature is > 100 C, and use this to generate useful work.

Answer (score 3):

> Since water boils at room temperature in a near vacuum, is it possible to use this to generate electricity in some way?

Yes. If something is making water boil, then there must be a flow of heat. You can build a heat engine that extracts useful work (e.g., to generate electricity) from that heat flow.

> Could this be possible in some way using a vacuum chamber to boil the water?

Vacuum doesn't make water boil. *Heat* makes water boil.

When water boils, the vapor carries heat away. If you suddenly expose an open container of water to vacuum, two things will happen: (1) the water will start to boil, and (2) the water will get colder as it boils. When the water gets cold enough---maybe cold enough to freeze solid---the boiling will stop.

In order to continuously boil water, at *any* pressure, you must have a continuous supply of heat.

---

So, what you didn't ask was, would pulling vacuum on the outlet of a steam turbine improve its efficiency?

Well, here's the kicker:  In large thermal power stations, [that is what they actually do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_power_station#Steam_condensing).

The working fluid in a large thermal power stations is de-mineralized water that flows in a *closed loop*.  There is nothing *but* water in the loop (i.e., no air), so at the cold end of the turbines, where the temperature may be as low as the temperature of the cooling water that they draw from a nearby river, the pressure can be much less than atmospheric---almost vacuum.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "no".  Steam turbines use hot, high pressure steam.  As this steam travels at high velocity through the turbine blades, it experiences pressure drop and a drop in temperature.  The resulting "loss" in steam energy is what produces the work that turns the turbine, which is connected to an electrical generator.

For water boiling under vacuum conditions, the steam is produced from the heat content of the water itself.  This heat content is limited, so the amount of steam produced is limited.  In addition, because the steam is produced under vacuum conditions, it has a very low density and a very low temperature, so there is not much steam energy available to do turbine work.  This fact becomes even more "onerous" when one considers the amount of work that must be done by the associated vacuum pump in order to produce the vacuum conditions required to boil the water.  Once the vacuum  pump work is considered, it becomes obvious that the efficiency of this process is WAY too low to be useful.

Comment: This answer relies on a myriad of assumptions that were not stated in the question. I'd be interested in an answer that didn't fill in the details to make a setup that obviously doesn't work in an uninteresting way, and instead get at the heart of the question. Assume the question asker is not a toddler.

Comment: @Vectorjohn, if you have a better answer, why didn't you post it?

Comment: sorry that my comment came off as snarky. I don't think I have to have a better answer to be able to point out reasons why this one is incorrect, or at least misleading. The answer to the question is only "no" if you make a lot of assumptions about the question that were not actually stated.

Comment: @Vectorjohn, I'm not trying to "toot my own horn" on this one, but I am a master's level chemical engineer with 21 years of industrial experience.  Due to that, I can anticipate all of the questions that the OP would think of asking, even if he hasn't asked them yet, and the answers to those questions are why his scheme won't work.

Comment: there is the problem. You didn't "anticipate all" their questions, you anticipated a straw man. Have you ever heard the term "steel manning" or "to steel man" someone? It means when they leave things unstated, you respond assuming the best version of an argument or question. 
In this case, the answer is not "no", it's actually "yes", you absolutely could spin a turbine by boiling water with a vacuum. 100% yes. In a small chamber, it would quickly stop. And if you continually run the pump, you'd spend more energy than you generate.

Comment: @Vectorjohn, I note that it's much easier to be a critic than it is to post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The second law of thermodynamics requires that for a heat engine to generate electricity, it must have a heat difference to exploit.

You could probably use the fact that water boils at low pressures to make a steam engine that ran on the difference between room temperature and 0 degrees C. But the pressure in the condensation chamber would have to be even lower than the pressure in the boiler, so the engine would probably have a very low power output.

If you were actually designing an engine to run on that kind of temperature difference, it would be better to use some working fluid other than water that could boil at room temperature, even under a high pressure.

Note: There is a reason why the water-based engine could not be run with a cold temperature that is much cooler than 0 degrees C. The reason is that the triple point of water is located at 0 degrees. So if you tried to keep the condenser much cooler than that, you'd have solid ice forming in your condenser: not a good thing.

Comment: You can build a heat engine that runs "with a cold temperature that is much cooler than 0 C." All you have to do is "use some working fluid other than water..."

Comment: @besmirched Okay, I've edited to clarify in my note that it only applies where the working fluid is water.

Comment: The best working fluid is helium, but the required temperature range is generally a tad cold for terrestrial use. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the function of a machine, no.

Some biophysics people propose that varying degrees of vacuum pressure may occur in certain confines molecular spaces in tissues.  E.G. this is a proposed mechanism for how tall trees, e.g. redwoods, are able to draw water up so high.  (because water evaporates from the leaves, and that leverages a vacuum force between the chain of water molecules that goes all the way to the roots.)

So in the above case, a biological vaccuum may be at work, using energy that would otherwise be lost to thermodynamic noise. This is not "generating electricity" per your question, but it is 'generating' *energy.*

Answer (score 1):

Great question - the answer is no. There's 3 reasons for that:

1. Water that boils from heat will continue to boil as long as there's more heat and water. Some other answer here mentions you need heat to boil. You absolutely do NOT need heat to boil. Heat is just used to overcome the pressure of the environment to boil, but if you take away the pressure of the environment, you don't need the heat. Take some water, put it on Pluto, and watch it boil with basically with near Absolute Zero temps and no heat source applied. This opens up the can of worms around Vapor Pressure and so on.
2. The moment that the water starts to boil from the vacuum container is also the same moment that the vacuum starts to go away (because there's vapor molecules filling up the container). So, as it starts to boil and increase the pressure in the container, the thing causing the boiling (the vacuum, NOT some 'heat source'), will disappear.
3. Turbines move because there's something of huge pressure moving it. Something like steam from boiling water, and you can keep adding more and more pressure and force by boiling more and more water. For simplicity, let's say a turbine starts to move at some arbitrary amount of force, say 100 psi, and you get that level of pressure by boiling a lot of water. You can boil all that water because you have all that pressure continuing to build due to boiling via a heat source.

When you boil the water via a lack of pressure, that pressure is starting out at 0 psi (it's a vacuum remember), and then when it boils, maybe you get to say 1 psi (the vacuum is being filled with water vapor), and the 1 psi isn't powerful enough to move anything. So you try to let it boil for a while, like you did with the boiling water, but only a moment later the water stops boiling, since it's no longer in a vacuum.

So the boiling water in a vacuum had 2 problems, a) it didn't last long at all, and b) it wasn't nearly pressurized enough to move anything.

There's a couple sloppy things I've stated here that maybe a PhD would have a problem with, but hopefully this is written in a way that starts to make intuitive sense.